# Presentations on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, presentation

Is there a lightweight package for doing powerpoint presentations on Lubuntu?  I have Abiword for wordprocessing and Gnumeric for spreadsheets,  but I'm not sure about Powerpoints?  I heard there was a thing called "Ease" or something but I don't know how to find it.

Comment: If by powerpoint pressentations you mean ppt files, use LibreOffice or a webapp.

Comment: isn't libre office too heavy for lubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using Lubuntu since version 11.04 and I use Libre Office.  Unless you have very little RAM you can as well.  Information concerning Ease can be found 
https://launchpad.net/~natesm/+archive/ease
and
https://launchpad.net/easeproject

Comment: I am now using Libreoffice as suggested, although I switched to Xubuntu - Lubuntu was a bit too "buggy" for my liking. It kept crashing!